# Connected subsets of set

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, connectedness

I have to find all connected subsets of {1/n, n$\in \mathbb{N} $ } $\cup $ {0}. I know all singletons of form {1/n} are connected. Is {0} connected?

I think it should be cause it cannot be split into 2 non empty seperated sets.

Answer (score 1):

On *any* topological space, every singleton is a connected set. So, yes, $\{0\}$ is connected. And no subset of that space with more than one point is connected, because if $S\subset\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n\,\middle|\,n\in\Bbb N\right\}$ has more than one pont, then one such point is $\frac1n$, for some $n\in\Bbb N$, and if you take $\delta>0$ so small that $\left[\frac1n-\delta,\frac1n+\delta\right]\cap S=\left\{\frac1n\right\}$, then $S\cap\left(\frac1n-\delta,\frac1n+\delta\right)$ is both closed and open in $\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n\,\middle|\,n\in\Bbb N\right\}$.

Comment: (1) Is this space discrete subspace of euclidean space? (2) Is  ${0}$ an open set ? (3) Is the space connected?  (4) What is the connected component of 0 ?

Comment: (1) No. (2) $0$ is a number, not a set. (3) Since I wrote that no subset with more than one point is connected, what do you think that my answer to this question will be? (4) Again, I wrote that no subset with more than one point is connected, and therefore the answer is $\{0\}$.

Comment: Sorry sir  (2) will be $\{0\}$ not $0$. Since all connected components are singleton hence the space is totally disconnected.

Comment: No, it is not an open set.

Comment: Yes. I understand sir. Since any open interval containing $0$ contains a point $\frac{1}{N}$.Hence , we can't write ${0}$ as intersection of that set and a open interval.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you sir for clearing my doubts. Thank you.